# Loop Design: Counting & Subsequent Code Duplication

Tags: c++, loops, code-duplication

Exercise 3-3 in Accelerated C++ has led me to two broader questions about loop design.  The exercise's challenge is to read an arbitrary number of words into a vector, then output the number of times a given word appears in that input.  I've included my relevant code below:

```
string currentWord = words[0];
words_sz currentWordCount = 1;
// invariant: we have counted i of the current words in the vector
for (words_sz i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
    if (currentWord != words[i]) {
        cout << currentWord << ": " << currentWordCount << endl;
        currentWord = words[i];
        currentWordCount = 0;
    }
    ++currentWordCount;
}
cout << currentWord << ": " << currentWordCount << endl;
```

Note that the output code has to occur again outside the loop to deal with the last word.  I realize I could move it to a function and simply call *the function* twice if I was worried about the complexity of duplicated code.

**Question 1:** Is this sort of workaround is common? Is there a typical way to refactor the loop to avoid such duplication?

**Question 2:** While my solution is straightforward, I'm used to counting from zero. Is there a more-acceptable way to write the loop respecting that? Or is this the optimal implementation?

Comment: `std::map<std::string, unsigned> word_count; for (const std::string& word : words) { word_count[word]++; } for (std::pair<std::string, unsigned> count : word_count) { std::cout << count.first << ": " << count.second << "\n"; }`. Or something.

Comment: Either the code is broken, or your description of the problem is off. You are here counting the number of successive occurrences, as `["cat", "dog", "cat"]` would output: `cat: 1`, `dog: 1`, `cat: 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use a map http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/ with word as key and value as the count?

Comment: The OP code is O(1) in space (baring initial input), your solution is not... because you are not solving the same problem.